# The public/private property for events

Tags: fullcalendar

A Google Calendar event (not the calendar itself) can be set as public or private in their web-interface. In the list of properties recognized by FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing) I haven't found a property for private/public events.

Ultimately, I need to display public events from a private calendar using FullCalendar, and I can't seem to find a property to filter by. Does FullCalendar recognize it?

Thanks!

Comment: No. FullCalendar will just display whatever events you give to it. So if you don't want an event to be displayed on the calendar, then don't include it in the list of events you send to the calendar. Most people have some server-side code which controls the list of events being created, so you can implement your public/private logic there, before the data reaches fullCalendar.

Comment: I might have been unclear, so I edited my question. Please see if it makes sense now.

Comment: Ok. So how are you loading the events from Google into fullCalendar?

Comment: I use a Wordpress plugin (Private Google Calendars) which works with FullCalendar. It transparently passes all properties FullCalendar supports and allows to display a calendar on a page, with events filtered by certain properties. I wondered if there's this property to filter events by that the plugin would use, but it has to be supported by FullCalendar.

Comment: It's possible to add custom properties to fullCalendar, and you could then write code to filter them. So maybe you can modify the plugin to do that. But honestly without knowing what the plugin is or seeing its source code it's a little difficult to be sure what the best approach is.

Comment: Regardless of how the plugin works, my question is: Google Calendar events on their own do have the per-event public/private setting. Does FullCalendar support that?

Comment: Not directly no. I answered that in my first comment already. Our discussion now, I thought, was about finding alternative ways you can achieve the same effect. Knowing how the plugin works will help me to understand what the best way might be.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Here's the plugin: https://blog.michielvaneerd.nl/private-google-calendars/#fullcalendar-shortcode

Comment: ok thanks. So explain to me again...if you have connected the plugin to a private calendar, you want to be able to filter the events within the calendar so that you can show only the ones marked "public" on fullCalendar? I think I get that. But do you also want the option to show the ones marked "private" (e.g. with a tickbox on the screen), or do you want them to just never be given to fullCalendar at all?

Comment: Right! I only want public events given to fullCalendar, as private events are displayed in a different way.

Comment: ok well I think you can probably filter them out in the PHP of the plugin. in the file private-google-calendars.php line 471 there's a loop which gets each Google Calendar item and creates a new object from it with the data in fullCalendar's format. So I expect you can check the public/private property of the Google Calendar entry in there, and decide whether or not to include it in the fullCalendar list or not. I can't try it right now but that seems to be the obvious way to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I will take this route, since 1) editing PHP would mean incompatibility with updates, and 2) there might be different workarounds on the calendar level (i.e. working with 2 separate calendars). But it's nice to know the solution exists if all else fails. Thanks for going to great lengths to help me!

Answer (score 0):

According to @ADyson, currently, there's no way to do that, but he kindly suggested an alternative way to achieve the ultimate goal. Thank you!